# Display different tableview data depending on which collectionview cell is selected

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

[Here's a screenshot of the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPhxX.png)

I have a collectionview above my tableview. I'm trying to get the tableview's data to change based on which collectionview cell is selected.

This view handles menu item selection, and menu items are displayed in the tableview. The categories for these menu items are displayed in a horizontally-scrolling collectionview right above the tableview.

The restaurant class has an instance variable `.categories` which returns an array of strings. This is what populates the collectionview. The menu item class has an instance variable `.category` which returns a single string. I intend to match these two.

My intended result: For each selected cell in the collectionview, take its category name and communicate it to the tableview. The tableview should take this name and filter through its menu items to check for matching category names. Display those specific tableview cells.

For my collectionview:

```swift
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = restaurant?.categories.count {
            return count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell

        // Sets label text and images for each category
        cell.categoryLabel.text = restaurant?.categories[indexPath.row]
        if UIImage(named: (restaurant?.categories[indexPath.row])!) != nil {
            cell.buttonView.image = UIImage(named: (restaurant?.categories[indexPath.row])!)
        }

        return cell
    }
```

For my tableview:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let count = restaurant?.menuItems.count {
            return count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = masterTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuItemCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

        let currentItem = restaurant?.menuItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.item = currentItem

        return cell
    }
```

Right now, my result (obviously) is that simply all of my menu items are being displayed in the tableview, regardless of which collectionview cell is selected.

Comment: print(restaurant?.categories) , this will give , **[popular, milk tea,  snacks, tea, ...]** [from ur screenshot image]. Am I right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things needed in following format for your question.

**1. restaurant?.categories values:**

```
[popular, milk tea, snacks, tea, ...]
```

**2. restaurant?.menuItems values:**

```
{
    popular : [
                {
                    "name" : "thai-tea",
                    "price": "$6",
                    "thumbnailURL" : "https://.../thai.png"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "milk-tea",
                    "price": "$3",
                    "thumbnailURL" : "https://.../ml.png"
                }
            ],
    snacks : [
                {
                    "name" : "brownie",
                    "price": "$7",
                    "thumbnailURL" : "https://.../brw.png"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "pasta",
                    "price": "$3",
                    "thumbnailURL" : "https://.../pas.png"
                }
            ]
}
```

**Global Variable**

```
var whichCellSelect : Int = 0
```

**CollectionView**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    whichCellSelect = indexPath.item
    yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Tableview**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let count = restaurant?.menuItems.count {
        return count
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = masterTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCell", for: indexPath) as! MenuItemCell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

    let currentCategory = restaurant?.categories[whichCellSelect] // You will get String here
    let currentMenuItem = restaurant?.menuItems[currentCategory] // You will get Array here
    cell.item = currentItem

    return cell
}
```

**Notes**

Make sure, restaurant?.categories data type as `[String]` and restaurant?.menuItems data type as `[String : Any]` . This is one of the simplest way to understand data transfer within `UIViewController`

Comment: Kindly upvote my answer too. It will be usefull for our SO followers

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this if the collection view enables multiple selection?

Comment: Yes we can!! Post ur question and share question link here., @alobaili

Comment: Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66543505/display-different-table-view-data-depending-on-which-collection-view-cell-is-sel

Answer (score 0):

How are the different categories stored? Are you using an array for each category and sending that specific array to  the TableView after an option in the CollectionView is selected? Then you would need to refresh the TableView so the changes are reflected in the interface.

I alsso can't see where you're getting what the user pressed in the CollectionView. ...  can you not use something like this ...

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

to get what they've selected, use that choice to update the table by writing a different array or only adding certain array elements depending on the category then use `reloadData()` to refresh the table.

Comment: Hey Jordan, just updated my post with a screenshot of my view; hope that helps a bit. As I stated in my question, the categories are stored as an array of strings. Each cell sets its label to the string, and matches an icon stored in assets to the string. My current implementation doesn't actually make use of the menu item's category. Your suggestion is along the lines of what I've been trying, and it works in theory. The actual implementation of it is much harder, however, and I'm not quite sure how to go about it.